# How to fix superposition artifacts

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

I have a step response function defined as:

```
response = 1.044871614559231` + 
  188851.40028652488` E^(-0.0008027739947742557` t) - 
  481567.05488752836` E^(-0.0007618214677503482` t) + 
  533421.153826132` E^(-0.0006976033182554547` t) - 
  381881.5025204858` E^(-0.0006157908128333724` t) + 
  210904.71677914335` E^(-0.0005235899247183814` t) - 
  101302.35227639876` E^(-0.0004290764551077835` t) + 
  45982.83099921907` E^(-0.00034042402473086035` t) - 
  20314.01115736056` E^(-0.0002650553359099233` t) + 
  8074.680386193031` E^(-0.0002087261148901471` t) - 
  1985.479134371541` E^(-0.00017465012059731007` t)
```

and I am trying to add up the responses to certain jumps:

```
jump = {10, 10, 10, 10, 90, 250, 580, 1930, 1910, 
  120, -730, -930, -650, -420, -300, -270, -240, -230, -230, -220,
-170, -130, -110, -100}
```

at certain times:

```
jumptime = {10800, 21600, 32400, 43200, 54000, 64800, 75600, 86400, 
  97200, 108000, 118800, 129600, 140400, 151200, 162000, 172800, 
  183600, 194400, 205200, 216000, 226800, 237600, 248400, 259200}
```

If I define the lag-response function by:

```
r[j_] := jump[[j]]*
   UnitStep[
    t - jumptime[[j]]]*(response /. t -> (t - jumptime[[j]])) // 
  Simplify
```

and calculate the superposition of lagged jumps by:

```
totalresponse = Sum[r[tt], {tt, 1, 23}];
```

I get artifacts in the solution:

[image]

which are due to large numbers not being cancelled out. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a large spike at the beginning of your `response`:

```
LogPlot[1 + response, {t, 0, 100000}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Remove it:

```
response2 = Piecewise[{{0, t < 10000}}, response];

r2[j_] := jump[[j]]*
   UnitStep[t - jumptime[[j]]]*(response2 /. t -> (t - jumptime[[j]])) // Simplify

totalresponse2 = Sum[r2[tt], {tt, 23}] // PiecewiseExpand;

Plot[totalresponse2, {t, 0, 350000}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use rationals rather than floating point numbers. Using your definitions of `response` and the `jump` variables:

```
res[t_] := Rationalize[#, 0] & /@ response;
r[j_] := jump[[j]]*UnitStep[t - jumptime[[j]]]*res[t - jumptime[[j]]];
totalresponse[t_] := Sum[r[tt], {tt, 1, 23}];
Plot[totalresponse[t], {t, 0, 250000}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice workaround. However, the solution should be a smooth curve. See, the curve is showing in my plot.